# Global OpenGL Texture

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I want to have a global gradient that goes all the way across the window but it only appears in certain objects with OpenGL. It's a bit like using a 'Clipping Mask' in Photoshop, here is an example on what I am trying to achieve.

(by the way I am doing this with LWJGL in Java, but that shouldn't affect to much.)

[image: Image example]

Answer (score 2):

Have the texture coordinates aligned with the screen coordinates of your objects. That will cause the texture to be mapped as you want to.

Comment: To add to that, you want the height to go from 0 to 1 over the entire screen.  So multiply the y vertex in the shape by 1 / screen height to get the texture coordinate for it.  i.e. screen is 1000 high, vertex at y position 500 would be (1 / 1000) * 500 = 0.5.